# define variable with scope the following process

Tags: bash, scripts

Is it in bash scripting possible to define a variable which is scoped to the following process? Something like:

```
X="123" echo "$X"
```

Ultimately, I want to do catch the output of some process and write that (with some other surrounding text as well) to some output file:

```
X=$(...) echo "...$X..." > output_file
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use separate statements like `X="123"; echo "$X"`?

Answer (score 2):

In general you're right, you can set variables in the environment of the command:

```bsh
VAR=value some_command_that_uses_variable_VAR
```

But be aware of the order of [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions):

```bsh
x=123 echo "$x"
```

the shell will expand `$x` **before** it evaluates `x=123`